# Issue when sending email in Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, smtp

I get the following error when trying to send an email:

> Unable to connect with STARTTLS: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.

I try to add `'auth_mode' => null, 'verify_peer' => false`, but it's not working for me.

Comment: Is `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` set to `null` in your `.env`? Is the `smtp.encryption` value in `config/mail.php` set to use `env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION')`? Have you cleared your config cache i.e. `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: No MAIL_ENCRYPTION  is set  tls in .env file. Yes i cleared the config cache but the problem is still here

Comment: certificates are up to date?